# Resizing/scaling image causes distortion

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an app widget and in it I'd like to show a scaled down version of my app's icon in the bottom right.  The image's dimensions are 36x36 and the image looks fine at those dimensions, but I'd like the image to be smaller, around 18x18.  However, if I resize the image in a image editor or try to scale the image in code, the image appears distorted.

This is what the image looks normally:

[image]

This is the image scaled:

[image]

This is the `ImageView` code I'm using:

```
<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/widgetIcon"
   android:src="@drawable/icon"
   android:layout_width="18dp"
   android:layout_height="18dp"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
   android:scaleType="centerCrop"
 />
```

**UPDATE:**

I actually have the image in different drawable folders, broken out like this:

drawable-ldpi: 36x36

drawable-mdpi: 48x48

drawable-hdpi: 72x72

drawable-xdpi: 96x96

The device I took the screenshots in is a Galaxy Nexus.

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is the entire layout that the `ImageView` is in, if that makes a difference.  The widget has `RelativeLayout` at the bottom that hold the `ImageView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/widgetLayout"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/widgetBgLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_widget"
         >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/widgetStatusLayout" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
          >
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/widgetStatus" 
                    style="@style/WidgetStatus"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
                />

                <ImageView 
                   android:id="@+id/widgetIcon"
                   android:src="@drawable/icon"
                   android:layout_width="18dp"
                   android:layout_height="18dp"
                   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   android:scaleType="centerInside"
                   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 />

            </RelativeLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_above="@id/widgetStatusLayout"       
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             >      
                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/widgetTitle" 
                        style="@style/WidgetTitle"
                    />

                    <TextView 
                        android:id="@+id/widgetText" 
                        style="@style/WidgetText"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**UPDATE 3**

The issue isn't with the image scaling, it's the layout above the image is overlapping.  Not sure of a solution though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the image into each of the different drawable folders (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xhdpi). This should help. Also, change the `android:scaleType` to `fitCenter`.

Comment: Actually, I misspoke in my OP.  I do have the images in different drawable folders, each with different dimensions.  I'll update my OP as the formatting is better.  However, I tried using `fitCenter` but got the same results.

Comment: Tried, `centerInside` no luck.  I updated my OP, again, to show the entire layout that the `ImageView` is in, if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried using the WYSIWYG? Take a look at that and see if the image is centered. You can also do some manipulation with the image by right clicking on the image and changing how it is scaled and such.

Comment: Cool, I'll try the built-in editor, however, in theory, setting the dimensions to 18dp should scale the image correctly?  I come from a web background and I know if you set the dimensions of a larger image to smaller than what is it, it will cause the image to distort.  Not sure if Android works the same.

Comment: You would think so, but to be honest, I'm not 100% sure. When I have worked with images on Android apps, I have done the same thing, setting a static size, and everything has been okay. I did use the WYSIWYG though, and that was helpful.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue, but not a solution.  The issue isn't that the image is getting distorted, it's the layout above the `ImageView` is overlapping, cutting it off.

Comment: That could be. That is how the editor can be helpful. It will show you the boarders of the different views and such. You will probably have an easier time figuring it out now.

Comment: Lol... They aren't that bad once you get use to them. There is definitely a learning curve though.